# Losing images when running program

Tags: python, directory

I'm running an os.rename program on thousands of images to rename them and sometimes it deletes hundreds of them. Luckily I made backups, but is there a way to stop this??

My code looks like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os, shutil
    _src = ("/Path/To/Directory")



    for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(_src)):

            newname = ('Truck-' + str(i).zfill(3))
            os.rename(os.path.join(_src, filename), os.path.join(_src,newname))


            print('renaming "%s" to "%s"...' % (filename, newname))
```

The only thing I can think of doing is somehow keeping the file loaded but I don't even know where to start on something like that.

Comment: How many files do you have there?

Comment: just about 3000.

Comment: They're all .png

Comment: Then `zfill(3)` is not good. Yet it doesn't look like *the* problem

Comment: @EugeneSh. is correct. Probably you should dynamically find the total number of files and get how many bits you need to represent that number. say N and then use zfill(N). But yeah thats not the solution. :/

Comment: Are you actually *counting* the files when you say they are missing, or how do you know?

Comment: If the source files are named `Truck-...` it could be a problem because the destination directory is the same as the source directory.

Comment: I'm highlighting the file and it tells me how many images there is and I can see jumps between numbers like it goes from Truck-101 to Truck-102 to Truck-140. I will try changing the zfill number.

Comment: Are Truck-103 to Truck-139 present in the `renaming %s to %s` output?

Comment: No they just get voided for some reason.